# Get all long texts from ME31L Scheduling agreements to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, abap, sap-erp, saprfc

We have some important information in the Long Texts in SAs:

[image: Text 1 & Text 2]

i can get text 1 and text 2 through excel script but the problem is the long texts:

[image: Long Texts]

I know it's possible via Remote Function Calls (RFCs) with RFC_READ_TEXT, but I never use that in Excel.

Can anyone help me with this specific function? the examples I found are not clear and I really need the data in excel.

Thanks in advance